# Completion of a Metric Space is Banach Space?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

> Let $X$ be a metric space and $\hat{X}$ its completion. Show that $\hat{X}$ is a Banach space.

I think this is false, but I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: Take any complete metric space that is not a Banach space. E.g. $[0,1]$ with the usual Euclidean metric.

Comment: Is $X$ finite dimensional ?

Comment: Question doesn't even make sense: a Banach space is defined on a vector space and an arbitrary metric space does not have a vector space structure, let alone a norm

Answer (score 2):

Take any complete metric space which is not a Banach space (such as $S^1$, endowed with the usual topology), which will then be homeomorphic to its completion. Therefore, it will not be a Banach space.

Comment: Why $S^1$ is not Banach space?

Comment: It's not even a vector space, right?!